If a iPhone is turned off will find my not share location?
Last night i lost my iPhone 14 and im certain i had battery and find my activated so someone had to turn it off. But wouldnt find my still share the last location i was at? Whenever i checked find my it says "no location found" and "no conection" please help.

If the device is turned off, you're depending on Find My network to be enabled, and for there to be another Apple device that can bounce pings on behalf of the lost device.
From https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my/

If your missing device can’t connect to the internet or has little to
no battery life, the Find My app can still help you track it down
using the Find My network — hundreds of millions of iPhone, iPad, and
Mac devices around the world. Nearby devices securely send the
location of your missing device to iCloud, then you can see where it
is in the Find My app. It’s all anonymous and encrypted to protect
everyone’s privacy.


You get a short window (I believe Apple says 24 hours and up to 5 hours on reserve) when the device is powered off to locate it with ultrawideband. This means you’re within 100 feet or so of the device. I can’t confirm if you get pings back to the servers when it’s in reserve ( my hunch is no) or if someone turned it off (again, my hunch is no as well).
Have you asked Apple how this works in a support call?
You have to enable send last location when powering off to get that ping to the servers. The servers can only receive your location automatically if there is cellular data and it’s in range of a tower or WiFi and in range of known networks.
The best you can do once it’s gone is follow these steps in order:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/101593

